Proof of Golomb's three randomness postulates for binary sequences
I want to prove that the binary sequence generated by a max-length linear feedback shift register (LFSR) satisfies Golomb's balance, run and autocorrelation postulates:

The numbers of zeros and ones differ by at most 1.

For a sequnce of length $n$, the total number of runs is $(n+1) / 2$, and the number of runs of length $k$ is $(n+1) / 2^{k+1}$

The autocorrelation function is 2-valued.



These are proved in Golomb's "Shift Register Sequences", revised edition, in section 4 starting on page 43.
